# How to replace all XHTML/HTML line breaks (<br>) with new lines?

Tags: php, regex, newline

I am looking for the best `br2nl` function.  I would like to replace all instances of `<br>` and `<br />` with newlines `\n`.  Much like the [nl2br()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php) function but the opposite.

I know there are several solutions in the PHP manual comments but I'm looking for feedback from the SO community on possible solutions.

Comment: Are you sure you want to replace the HTML/XHTML line break elements with physical line breaks? Because `nl2br` does not replace the physical line breakts but just *adds* HTML/XHTML line break elements.

Comment: I'm not using this function to negate or recover a string that was returned from nl2br.  I am using it to sanitize text in a legacy database (from a webapp that allowed html) before I import it into my database.  I just said the opposite of nl2br because people generally know that function.

Answer (score 104, accepted):

I would generally say "*don't use regex to work with HTML*", but, on this one, I would probably go with a regex, considering that `<br>` tags generally look like either :

- `<br>`
- or `<br/>`, with any number of spaces before the `/`

I suppose something like this would do the trick :

```
$html = 'this <br>is<br/>some<br />text <br    />!';
$nl = preg_replace('#<br\s*/?>#i', "\n", $html);
echo $nl;
```

Couple of notes :

- starts with `<br`
- followed by any number of white characters : `\s*`
- optionnaly, a `/` : `/?`
- and, finally, a `>`
- and this using a case-insensitive match (`#i`), as `<BR>` would be valid in HTML

Comment: To be very nit-picky =] : `<input type="text" value="<br />">` is allowed in html (not xhtml). And in a CDATA section `<br />` is "normal" text.

Comment: @VolkerK : humph, true :-) ;; I was writting this using DOM, and when I finished, I saw you posted the same kind of solution I would have proposed *(excepts I used getElementsByName, and not XPath)*, so didn't post it -- maybe I should edit my answer, though, for the sake of completness, as it's been accepted...

Comment: But this solution is faster and less memory consuming (if this is a matter). If you don't have _completely_ arbitrary documents I'd probably consider these edge-cases acceptable.

Comment: Shouldn't the second argument be "\\n"? this is the only thing that works on my setup here.

Comment: My HTML looks like <br style="color: rgb(34, 34, 34); font-family: &quot;Open Sans&quot;, &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 15px;">

Answer (score 8):

You should be using `PHP_EOL` constant to have platform independent newlines.

In my opinion, using non-regexp functions whenever possible makes the code more readable.

```
$newlineTags = array(
  '<br>',
  '<br/>',
  '<br />',
);
$html = str_replace($newlineTags, PHP_EOL, $html);
```

I am aware this solution has some flaws, but wanted to share my insights still.

Comment: And regular expressions require usually heavier computations.

Comment: @BenBITDesign Regarding your suggested edit, please note that it is *absolutely not true* that regex in general requires more computation. In fact, without having timed this specific case it’s quite likely that the PCRE engine can perform this replacement more efficiently than `str_replace`, especially when just-in-time compilation is enabled.

Answer (score 2):

If the document is well-formed (or at least well-formed-ish) you can use the [DOM extension](http://docs.php/dom) and xpath to find and replace all br elements by a \n text node.

```
$in = '<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html><head><title>...</title></head><body>abc<br />def<p>ghi<br />jkl</p></body></html>';

$doc = new DOMDOcument;
$doc->loadhtml($in);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);

$toBeReplaced = array();
foreach($xpath->query('//br') as $node) {
    $toBeReplaced[] = $node;
}

$linebreak = $doc->createTextNode("\n");
foreach($toBeReplaced as $node) {
    $node->parentNode->replaceChild($linebreak->cloneNode(), $node);
}

echo $doc->savehtml();
```

prints

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head><title>...</title></head>
<body>abc
def<p>ghi
jkl</p>
</body>
</html>
```

edit: shorter version with only one iteration

```
$in = '<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html><head><title>...</title></head><body>abc<br />def<p>ghi<br />jkl</p></body></html>';

$doc = new DOMDOcument;
$doc->loadhtml($in);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);

$linebreak = $doc->createTextNode("\n");
foreach($xpath->query('//br') as $node) {
  $node->parentNode->removeChild($node);
}

echo $doc->savehtml();
```

Comment: You don’t need to do two rounds. You can replace the nodes with the first `foreach`.

Comment: That seems to be so ;-) For some (unknown) reason I remembered it to break the xpath iterator.

Comment: Shorter version doesn't add the `$linebreak` node. Anyway this is exactly what I needed, thanks.

Comment: The same with the linebreak replacement and without xpath: https://3v4l.org/UiJ1m#v8.2.7

Answer (score 1):

From the [nl2br](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php) comments:

```
<?php
function br2nl($string){
  $return=eregi_replace('<br[[:space:]]*/?'.
    '[[:space:]]*>',chr(13).chr(10),$string);
  return $return;
}
?>
```

Comment: the posix regular expression module has been deprecated. From the ereg\_replace manual page: "This function has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.3.0 and REMOVED as of PHP 6.0.0. Relying on this feature is highly discouraged."

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [@antti](https://stackoverflow.com/users/980399/antti) for accepted answer, [@konstantin-xflash-stratigenas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1832222/konstantin-xflash-stratigenas) who pointed to a defect
`<br style="color:#FFA;" />`
i try write a better regex to cover them too:

```php
$html = 'this <br>is<br/>some<br />text <br    />, <br//>, <br xyz/>!';

$html_nl = preg_replace('/<br[^>]*>/i', "\n", $html);

echo htmlspecialchars($html_nl);
```

although this not cover the [@volkerk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4833/volkerk) pointed defect yet