# File I/O to textarea in PHP

Tags: php, file-io

My friend and I have a little spare time home page together. He's not a programmer, and in order for him to be able to change some text on the front page, I created a php-script that

1) Reads data from file "tester.txt" (this is the text that should go on the front page)
2) Prints this text to a textarea, where you can edit the text and submit it again
3) Writes the edited text to the same file, "tester.txt"

The two functions Read(); and Write(); look like this

```
function Read() {
    $file = "tester.txt";
    $fp = fopen($file, "r");
    while(!feof($fp)) {
        $data = fgets($fp, filesize($file));
        echo "$data <br>";
    }
    fclose($fp);
}

function Write() {
    $file = "tester.txt";
    $fp = fopen($file, "w");
    $data = $_POST["tekst"];
    fwrite($fp, $data);
    fclose($fp);
}
```

The only problem I have is that when the text is printed to a text area the line returns are written as `<br>` - and I don't really want it to do that, because when you edit some of the code and rewrites it, another layer of `<br>`'s appear. Here's a screenshot to illustrate:

[image: Test 1]

[image: Test 2]

Is there any workaround to this?

Thanks!

If you need the rest of the code, here it is:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Updater</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
               function Read() {
                   $file = "tester.txt";
                   $fp = fopen($file, "r");
                   while(!feof($fp)) {
                       $data = fgets($fp, filesize($file));
                       echo "$data <br>";
                   }
                   fclose($fp);
               }

               function Write() {
                   $file = "tester.txt";
                   $fp = fopen($file, "w");
                   $data = $_POST["tekst"];
                   fwrite($fp, $data);
                   fclose($fp);
               }
        ?>

        <?php
        if ($_POST["submit_check"]){
            Write();
        };
        ?>      

        <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="post">
        <textarea width="400px" height="400px" name="tekst"><?php Read(); ?></textarea><br>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Update text">
        <input type="hidden" name="submit_check" value="1">
        </form>

                <?php
        if ($_POST["submit_check"]){
            echo 'Text updated';
        };
        ?>      


    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is simpler than you think. You shouldn't be outputting the `<br>` tags as the textarea already contains the entered newline characters (`\r\n` or `\n`). You don't have to read the file like that, if you read it this way, you never have to worry about the character contents.

Change:

```
$fp = fopen($file, "r");
while(!feof($fp)) {
    $data = fgets($fp, filesize($file));
    echo "$data <br>";
}
fclose($fp);
```

to:

```
echo file_get_contents( $file);
```

Problem solved.

Comment: Of course you will need to delete your current text file as it contains a bunch of `<br>` tags, but after that, you should never see any `<br>` tags again.

Answer (score 2):

This is happening because while writing the contents to the text area, you're putting a `<br>` at the end of each line. But in a textarea line breaks are noted by `"\n"`. When you're saving your existing text, the next time the line breaks are replaced with more `<br>`.

While printing out the content on a public page, keep the 
. But in the editing page, remove the br.

Here's what I would have done with the PHP code:

```
<?php
    define("FILE_NAME", "tester.txt");

    function Read()
    {
        echo @file_get_contents(FILE_NAME);
    }

    ;

    function Write()
    {
        $data = $_POST["tekst"];
        @file_put_contents(FILE_NAME, $data);
    }

    ?>

    <?php
    if ($_POST["submit_check"])
    {
        Write();
    }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You use `echo "$data <br>";` - just make that `echo $data;` ?

Answer (score 0):

At a guess, this is hosted on a *nix machine, and he is using a Windows machine to do the editing?

If this is the case, changing your write function to this should solve the problem:

```
function Write(){
    $file = "tester.txt";
    $fp = fopen($file, "w");
    $data = str_replace(array("\r\n","\r"),"\n",$_POST["tekst"]);
    fwrite($fp, $data);
    fclose($fp);
};
```

Comment: text edited in TextEdit for Mac :) and code in AptanaStudio - also for mac

Comment: Mac may produce the same issue, try the above function and see if it resolves it. This is all about the style of line breaks between systems.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the `<br>`'s. Depending how your `<textarea>` is configured, by default lines are hard wrapped using `\n`'s. These are preserved when you save the file, therefore you don't need to add your own line breaks.

Comment: Point is, I don't write the `<br>`'s! They appear on their own

Comment: You write them with `echo "$data <br>";`

Answer (score -1):

Use regex to replace the break tag with a newline character

```
preg_replace('#<br\s*/?>#i', "\n", $data);
```

You can find a more detailed explanation [answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2436145/br2nl-replace-all-xhtml-html-line-breaks-with-newlines-in-php)