# How to handle text with `ln` using PDO

Tags: php, javascript, html, sql, pdo

I am using PDO to execute queries. I have this problem: I have a `<textarea>` element from witch I am getting the text and post it to the server side and add it to the db after I am preparing it with PDO prepare:

```
$insertQuery = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO feedback (userName, comment, time_stamp, languageCode, userIp) VALUES (:usernaem, :comment, '". $now ."', :lang, '". $ip ."')");
$insertQuery->bindValue(':comment',nl2br($_POST['comment']));
...
```

In some other place in my web I am getting this "comment" back from the db and fetch it to json string:

```
  try {
    $commentQuery = $db->query("SELECT userName, time_stamp, comment, languageCode FROM feedback LIMIT 10");
  } catch (PDOException $ex) {
    die(json_encode(array('outcome' => false, 'message' => $ex->getMessage())));
  }

  $result = $commentQuery->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);}
  $commentsJson = json_encode($result);
```

the `$commentsJson` I am inserting to some javascript var:

```
var comments = JSON.parse('<?php echo $commentsJson; ?>');
```

and here my chrome browser throws an exception.

### For example:

if I have this text in my `<textarea>`:
 and I submit it to the db:

> This is some comment
>
> and this is new line of comment

in the db it saved as:

```
This is some comment<br />
and this is new line of comment
```

But when I am getting it back from the db I am getting this:

```
 var comments = JSON.parse('[{"userName":"Test","time_stamp":"2013-04-04 10:17:43","comment":"This is some comment<br \/>\nand this is new line of comment", ...
```

and after that I have my browser exception saying:

> "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token"

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Could you do me a favor and run your json through http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/ . It'll point out any mal formed sections and that way we can know if it's a problem with the json or a problem with the javascript.

Comment: Ok, try using this SO answer to remove the br's
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2436145/br2nl-replace-all-xhtml-html-line-breaks-with-newlines-in-php

Comment: I don't sure were to use it. In witch step?

Comment: You could change the fetch all to a foreach and in the comment section change the br's to new lines. I don't really know what's wrong with your code to be totally honest. If it's valid json code then JSON.parse shouldn't be erroring out. I'm just trying to trouble shoot through things I think may be wrong.

Comment: I have added (and edited the question) `$insertQuery->bindValue(':comment',nl2br($_POST['comment']));` function.

Comment: PDO has nothing to do with line breaks. Your problem is somewhere else.

Comment: So remove the nl2br function @Your Common Sense

Comment: it doesn't matter. with nl2br, or without this function - 
PDO does not interfere with data. PDO can store **any** data and it will retrieve it intact. Your problem is somewhere else.

Comment: I think that the problem is that  `json_encode` adds `\n` and `JSON.parse` dont know how to handle it. I tried to escape it but with no success...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

ok after half day of research i have made this:

```
<?php
$result = $commentQuery->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$commentsJson = json_encode($result);
?>
...
function replacetext(text, what, to){
      var searchfor = what.replace(/\r/gi,'').replace(/[-[\]{}()*+?.,\\^$|#\s]/g, "\\$&");
      var replacewith = to.replace(/\r/gi,'');
      var flags = 'gi';
      var searchexp = new RegExp(searchfor,flags);
      text = text.replace(searchexp,replacewith);
      return text;
   }

    var tmp = '<?php echo $commentsJson; ?>';
    tmp = replacetext(tmp, "\n", '<br>');
```

Thanks for the help!