# PHP nl2br function

Tags: php, nl2br

I have a `<textarea>` in which i save a message which is send to the user who register in my site.
Means i can modify the message from my admin panel.

i use

```
$message = nl2br($_POST['message']);
```

This command to store $message in DB everytime whenever i update the message so that it can treat my Enter as a `<br>`..
But now suppose if i update the message without making any changes it will add a `<br>` to the `<br>` (2 line breaks).

I enter in the textarea

```
Hi 
Thanx for contact Us
```

It will store it as

```
Hi<br>
Thanx for contacting us<br>
```

Now if i add a line to it

```
Hi<br>
Thanx for contacting us<br>
-Team MCXIndiaLive
```

It will store it as

```
Hi<br><br>
Thanx for contacting us<br><br>
-Team MCXIndiaLive
```

How can i stop that???

Comment: Store the original too and present that when editing. OR store only the original call `nl2br` upon presenting it to the user.

Comment: You might find this useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2436145/br2nl-replace-all-xhtml-html-line-breaks-with-newlines-in-php

Comment: Only use `nl2br` when *displaying*, not when *storing*.

Comment: @ Oli Charlesworth  : Thanxx.. it does the work.. :)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a better way is storing it 'Clean'. So without the line breaks.

When you display the test you'll add the nl2br, so when you'll edit the text the line breaks won't be added twice.