# How to remove <br /> from textarea after load from database?

Tags: php, sql

[image]

I am getting `<br />` for every newline in textarea after I load the values from the database

I try to use these but it does not change anything

`nl2br($house_address);`

Any tips?

Comment: `$address = str_replace('<br />', '', $address)` or `$address = strip_tags($address)`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2436145/br2nl-replace-all-xhtml-html-line-breaks-with-newlines-in-php  regexp there will help

Answer (score 6):

Use [`strip_tags`](https://www.php.net/strip_tags):

```
echo strip_tags($house_address);
```

Answer (score 4):

`nl2br` does the opposite of what you want to do.

you could do

```
$house_address = str_replace('<br />', "\n", $house_address);
```

or this

```
$house_address = preg_replace('#<br\s*/?>#', "\n", $house_address);
```

Also, You really should do this *before* you insert the data into the database (or preferably `strip_tags($house_address)`).

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
 $address = str_replace('<br />', '\n\t', $address);
 $address = str_replace('<br>', '\n\t', $address);
```

OR

```
$address = str_ireplace('<br />', '\n\t', $address);
```

Answer (score 1):

`nl2br($house_address)` replaces new lines with the `<br />`, you don't need to use it.

Do you store `<br/>`'s in a database? Is so, use `strip_tags()` to strip them.

It's much better to store the plain text and process it prior the output.