# using htmlspecialchars() to preserve character meaning but omit <br/> in output display

Tags: php, sql-server, formatting, htmlspecialchars, nl2br

I need to format a string

```
$string = "<em>Hello</em><br/>world";
```

to display as:

```
<em>Hello</em>
world
```

All html characters should display as they are to preserve their meaning, except for `<br/>`, `\n`, etc..

The `<br/>` tag should still do what it's meant to do, break the line, but all other tags need to be shown as above.

I want to accomplish this with something like this:

```
htmlspecialchars($string); // except for the <br/> or \n tags
```

The `$string` value needs to be inserted into a database table in such a way that the output would show as seen above.

Using PHP, what would be the best way to accomplish this

Answer (score -1):

Try to replace `<br>` with `\n`

```
$html = '<em>Hello</em><br/>world';
$nl = preg_replace('#<br\s*/?>#i', "\n", $html);
echo $nl;
```

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2436181/552807

Comment: nice crack, although I think you're misunderstanding the question. I need a solution to enable a certain output as described above. If you're confused please post a comment and I'll try and elaborate