# Breaking line tag crushes the mb_substr function

Tags: php, html, substr

I have a posting system (like facebook) with something like the See More tool and the post body is stored in the database with its breaking line tags.

when I set the trimmed characters to any number, sometimes it stops inside the breaking line tag and crushes.

Is there a solution?

```
$stringCut = mb_substr($string, 0, 300);
$stringRest= mb_substr($string, 300);
```

Comment: What is a breaking line tag. Do you mean to say you store HTML in the database?

Comment: I mean `<br>` tag

Comment: Why do you store that in the database?

Comment: to make breaks between lines. is that a problem?

Comment: Yes, because then you can't do what you wanted to do with mb_substr. If this is the only reason you store HTML in the database then I would recommend to use `\n` instead.

Comment: I have a large database and I can`t replace all the `<br>` with `\n`, is there another solution?

Comment: Is there any other HTML content apart from `<br>` in this field?

Comment: no, only this tag, in tens of thousands

Comment: As a workaround you can consider this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2436145/1839439

Comment: actually, I am not looking for replacing the tag with PHP tool, what I want is not to stop inside the tag (take it fully, or leave it fully)